# Improperly configured django error

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a simple django project and whenever i run it, it gives me an improperly configured error. Tells me my model is missing a query set:

[Improperly Configured Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn7KS.png)

## Here's the code for my views.py. The functionality doesn't matter for now:

```
import random
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView



class RestaurantList(ListView):
    querySet = Restaurant.objects.all()
    template_name = 'restaurants/restaurants_list.html'

class SpicyList(ListView):
    template_name = 'restaurants/restaurants_list.html'
    querySet = Restaurant.objects.filter(category__iexact='spicy')

class AsianList(ListView):
   template_name = 'restaurants/restaurants_list.html'
   querySet = Restaurant.objects.filter(category__iexact='asian')
```

## Here's the code for my models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    loocation = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

## urls.py code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from restaurant.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html')),
    url(r'^restaurants/$', RestaurantList.as_view()),
    url(r'^restaurants/asian/$', AsianList.as_view()),
    url(r'^restaurants/spicy/$', SpicyList.as_view()),
    url(r'^Contact/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='Contact.html')),   
    url(r'^About/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='About.html'))        
]
```

It's only the urls containing 'restaurants' that give me this error. The rest are fine.

## Here's a picture of my file structure at the side

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KXtI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `queryset` attribute should be **lower case** at all.

all your `views` contain `querySet`

replace them by `queryset` *lower case*

Or you can provide the model attribute `model = ModelName`

See more In the [Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

Comment: Oh wow had no idea that was case sensitive. Thank you for your help